# Teamcity 8 + MSTest + DotCover - Not generating coverage report

Tags: teamcity, mstest, dotcover

The test coverage has been working fine with the same setup and fail to figure out what got updated recently (checked build configuration changes and vsdl/testconfig changes).

The only difference I see in logs (between a build with coverage and a build without any coverage) is this:

*No executable code was detected. 
The issue could be caused by one of the following:
- Include / exclude patterns are incorrect
- Assemblies are compiled without debugging information
- .pdb files are not available
- Visual Studio code coverage is enabled for MSTest
- .testrunconfig is used for MSTest and Visual Studio code coverage is not disabled (CodeCoverage section with enable="true" is present)*

Checked all of these. and none seem to be the issue.
Any suggestions?

I found few other questions with similar problem but none of the suggested solutions worked in my case:

Previous suggested solutions:
1) [Invalid filters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898209/cant-get-correct-assembly-filters-to-work-with-teamcity-8-and-dotcover-code-cov)
remove all filters, still no coverage report.

2) [Invalid access permissions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320321/dotcover-in-teamcity-8-doesnt-work)
No exception seen in logs. Nothing like 'rejected coverage report'

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid without logs it will be impossible to find the cause of the problem. If you add the 'teamcity.agent.dotCover.log' configuration parameter to the build configuration with a path to an empty directory on the agent, all dotCover log files will be placed there and TeamCity will publish zipped logs as hidden build artifact: '.teamcity/.NETCoverage/dotCoverLogs.zip'. You can send the information to this e-mail address: support@jetbrains.com.